# Hibernate: Primary key made of foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I have "OrderItem" class. Its primary key its suppose to be made of "productID" and "orderID" (both FK reference from another entities).
How can I set that up using annotations?

Thanks in advance!!!!

***Table***:
ordersItems
***Attributes***:
productID (PK-PK)  ------------------> Product
orderID (PK-PK)    ------------------> Order

Given these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name="productID")
    private Integer id;
    private String description;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    private int orderID;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderID")
    private List<OrderItem> items;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ordersItems")
public class OrderItem{

    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="productID")
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private float price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make an embeddable domain class that has only the fields in your primary key built of foreign keys. The annotation is at the class level, @Embeddable, on the foreign key domain class.

Here is the docs for EmbeddedId

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html

Comment: But here's the thing... I can add those 2 attributes with the annotations in that and the ones is Order.The trouble come when I have to set them as the @Id.
I tried with the EmbbeddedID creating 2 new attributes with the same name as the FK but it didnt work. As expected hibernate throws: " Repeated column in mapping for entity..."
Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply until now. Can you update your question with your latest code you have tried?